# Вывести строку, которая состоит из первых букв каждого слова в введенной строке JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, циклы

Пользователь вводит строку и нужно вывести строку, которая состоит из первых букв каждого слова в введенной строке.

Кто может помочь?

Comment: В первом приближении так: `str.split(' ').map(word => word[0]).join();`

Comment: Как именно определяется слово в строке?

Comment: Во, @Grundy зрит в корень. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = prompt("ваша строка")
const formatted = str.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, " ")
// буквы и цифры
// if (/^[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\s]+$/.test(formatted)) {}
// только буквы, без цифр
if (/^[A-Za-zА-Яа-я\s]+$/.test(formatted)) {
  const result = formatted.split(" ").reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur[0], "")
  console.log(result)
} else {
  console.log("неверный ввод, только буквы")      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const string = prompt('Введите строку')

if (string) {
  const result = string.split(' ').reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const first = currentValue[0] || ''
    accumulator = accumulator + first
    return accumulator
  }, '')
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: `one  two` -> `oneundefinedt`

Comment: Теперь `one  two` -> `onet`, а надо `ot`

Comment: Инициализировал reduce, если вы не против)

Comment: не против, спасибо)